# Allow only certain senders to a mailing list

Tags: postfix

How do I set up postfix so that only `me@example.com` and `you@example.com` are allowed to send email to the address `list@example.com`?

I've seen some guides that do a similar thing, but not quite for this example. Also, the postfix manual is complex, so I'd appreciate an example snippet that does the job. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Protecting internal email distribution lists (postfix)

Take a look at [Protecting internal email distribution lists](http://www.postfix.org/RESTRICTION_CLASS_README.html#internal) at http://www.postfix.org . The last example seems to be what you want.

/etc/postfix/main.cf:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
    ...
    check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/protected_destinations
    ...the usual stuff...

smtpd_restriction_classes = insiders_only
insiders_only = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/insiders, reject
```

/etc/postfix/protected_destinations (needs compilation with `postmap`):

```
list@example.com   insiders_only
```

/etc/postfix/insiders (needs compilation with `postmap`):

```
me@example.com   OK
you@example.com  OK
```

Comment: Sorry, like I said I can't make sense of the postfix manual examples. Can anyone tell me where I put the list of allowed senders (me@..., you@..., etc.) and where I put the name of the mailing list (list@...)?